# Pinhole matrix problem

Tags: camera, matrix, projection

I made a program to represent a 3D world. I use the projection matrix we can find on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection#Perspective_projection). For viewing a scene it's very nice but when I straff in the scene, everything behind the camera go on the screen.

Comparaison image:

[image]

Can you tell me how I can fix it, just the main idea ? Is it the frustum ?

```
Point2D Point3D::convertPerspective(){
    // camera pin hole
    // translation
    Point3D newPoint = *this-camera;
    // rotation
    Point3D d(cos(theta.y)*(sin(theta.z)*newPoint.y+cos(theta.z)*newPoint.x)-sin(theta.y)*newPoint.z,
              sin(theta.x)*(cos(theta.y)*newPoint.z+sin(theta.y)*(sin(theta.z)+cos(theta.z)*newPoint.x))+cos(theta.x)*(cos(theta.z)*newPoint.y-sin(theta.z)*newPoint.x),
              sin(theta.x)*(cos(theta.y)*newPoint.z+sin(theta.y)*(sin(theta.z)+cos(theta.z)*newPoint.x))-sin(theta.x)*(cos(theta.z)*newPoint.y-sin(theta.z)*newPoint.x));
    //projection
    return Point2D((viewerPos.z/d.z)*d.x-viewerPos.x,
                   (viewerPos.z/d.z)*d.y-viewerPos.y);
}
```

Comment: You're certain you're creating the matrix correctly? It's hard (for me at least) to tell exactly what's happening just from the images above. Including a code snippet of how you're constructing the matrix may be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume you are trying to write your own software renderer or something like that.

From how you describe it, it appears you don't do any clipping. But since you seem to only draw lines, this can be easily fixed, just only draw the part of the lines that are in front of the camera:

1. For every line, check on what side of the clipping plane the vertices are.
2. If both vertices are behind the plane, don't draw anything.
3. If both vertices are in front, draw them normally.
4. If only one of the vertices is behind the camera, replace it with the intersection point of the line and the clipping plane, then apply projection matrix and draw the vertices.

You might want to apply this check for all clipping planes of your frustum, depending on how complex your scene will be, as clipping also helps performance.

Also if you are going to draw polygons, be aware that clipping those is a bit more complicated. Have a look at these [clipping algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clipping_%28computer_graphics%29#Algorithms) for information on how to do it.